# Largest/Smallest eigenvalue of a hessian

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Currently I am trying to prove the lower boundary of a certain quantity. To be more specific, the denominator of the Zouterdijk equation.

$\cos \left(\theta_k\right)=\frac{-\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)^{\top} \boldsymbol{p}_k}{\left\|\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)\right\|\left\|\boldsymbol{p}_k\right\|}=\frac{\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)^{\top}\left[\nabla^2 f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)+\tau_k\right]^{-1} \nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)}{\left\|\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)\right\|\left\|\boldsymbol{p}_k\right\|}$

$\cos \left(\theta_k\right) \geq \frac{\frac{1}{8.1}\left\|\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)\right\|^2}{\left\|\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)\right\|\left\|\boldsymbol{p}_k\right\|}=\frac{\left\|\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)\right\|}{8.1\left\|\boldsymbol{p}_k\right\|}$

My question is about this term:

$\left[\nabla^2 f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_k\right)+\tau_k\right]^{-1}$

I do not understand how that term can be interchanged with an eigenvalue of the matrix.

For the proof the following relations need to be used:

$\lambda_1=\min _{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n:\|\boldsymbol{x}\|^2=1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\top} A \boldsymbol{x} \quad$ and $\quad \lambda_n=\max _{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n:\|\boldsymbol{x}\|^2=1} \boldsymbol{x}^{\top} A \boldsymbol{x}$.

Question:

- Can somebody clarify why it is allowed to interchange a matrix with an eigenvalue
- How do I need to interprete  the last relations? (In more basic language?)

Comment: There are several details missing here. What is $\mathbf{p}_k$? Is it $(\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x}_k)+\tau_k)^{-1}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$? Also, is $\tau_k$ a scalar (and a stand-in for $\tau_kI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix), or is it a matrix itself? Also, where does $\frac{1}{8.1}$ come from? Is it the eigenvalue that you're referring to? What does it have to do with $(\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x}_k)+\tau_k)^{-1}$? Which step, in particular, are you asking us about? Without this knowledge, it's difficult to to answer definitively.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of a symmetric matrix $A$ satisfies $\lambda_1 = \min_{u : \|u\|^2 = 1} u^\top A u$. In particular, this means that for any nonzero vector $v$, we have
$$v^\top A v = \|v\|^2 \left((v/\|v\|)^\top A (v/\|v\|)\right)
\ge \lambda_1 \|v\|^2.$$

The inequality in your post is the above for $v=\nabla f(x_k)$ and $A=[\nabla^2 f(x_k) + \tau_k I]^{-1}$ (assuming the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ is $\ge 1/8.1$).

Note also that if $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n$ are the eigenvalues of $H:=\nabla^2 f(x_k)$, then $(\mu_1 + \tau_k)^{-1}, \ldots, (\mu_n + \tau_k)^{-1}$ are the eigenvalues of $A = (H+\tau_k I)^{-1}$.